# How does the loop help iterate in this code

Tags: python

The problem at hand is that given a string `S`, we can transform every letter individually to be lowercase or uppercase to create another string.

Desired result is a list of all possible strings we could create.

Eg:

### Input:

```
 S = "a1b2"
```

### Output:

```
["a1b2", "a1B2", "A1b2", "A1B2"]
```

I see the below code generates the correct result, but I'm a beginner in Python and can you help me understand how does loop line 5 & 7 work, which assign value to res.

```
def letterCasePermutation(self, S):
    res = ['']
    for ch in S:
        if ch.isalpha():
            res = [i+j for i in res for j in [ch.upper(), ch.lower()]]
        else:
            res = [i+ch for i in res]
    return res
```

Comment: Lines 5 and 7 are [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

The `res`ult is a list of all possible strings up to this point.  One call to the function handles the next character.

If the character is a non-letter (line 7), the comprehension simply adds that character to each string in the list.

If the character is a letter, then the new list contains *two* strings for each one in the input: one with the upper-case version added, one for the lower-case version.

If you're still confused, then I strongly recommend that you make an attempt to understand this with standard debugging techniques.  Insert a couple of useful print statements to display the values that confuse you.

def letterCasePermutation(self, S):
    res = ['']
    for ch in S:
        print("char = ", ch)
        if ch.isalpha():
            res = [i+j for i in res for j in [ch.upper(), ch.lower()]]
        else:
            res = [i+ch for i in res]
        print(res)

```
return res
```

letterCasePermutation(None, "a1b2")

Output:

```
char =  a
['A', 'a']
char =  1
['A1', 'a1']
char =  b
['A1B', 'A1b', 'a1B', 'a1b']
char =  2
['A1B2', 'A1b2', 'a1B2', 'a1b2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to analyze this code is include the line:

```
print(res)
```

at the end of the outer for loop, as first answer suggests.
Then run it with the string '123' and the string 'abc' which will isolate the two conditionals. This gives the following output:

```
['1']
['12']
['123']
```

and

```
['A','a']
['AB','Ab','aB','ab']
['ABC','ABc','AbC','aBC','Abc','aBc','abC','abc']
```

Here we can see the loop is just taking the previously generated list as its input, and if the next string char is not a letter, is simply tagging the number/symbol onto the end of each string in the list, via string concatenation. If the next char in the initial input string is a letter, however, then the list is doubled in length by creating two copies for each item in the list, while simultaneously appending an upper version of the new char to the first copy, and a lower version of the new char to the second copy. 
For an interesting result, see how the code fails if this change is made at line 2:

```
res = []
```